# Make sure a count(*) select does not return the same value for two callers

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

In our web app (Java/JDBC), we use MySQL and we need it to store individual payment bills. Each bill must have a unique bill number. Currently, when storing a new bill, the bill number of the new bill is computed via the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bills;
```

My question: how do we ensure that no two bills get the same bill number?

Comment: Create a unique constraint: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/

Comment: Why not use UUID?

Comment: This will fail when you scale. Have the database maintain the counter instead.  Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: @P.Salmon Nice, but does not meet our requirements: For a bill number `x`, we need to generate the bill reference number as `(x + 100)C`, where `C` is the checksum.

Answer (score 3):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is the "right" way to achieve your goal.

`COUNT(*)` won't work if a row is ever deleted!

Here is a way to make your attempt work:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT MAX(bill_num)+1 FROM Bills  FOR UPDATE;
...
INSERT ... INTO Bills;
COMMIT;
```

The combination of using a transaction and `FOR UPDATE` prevents another connection from interferring.

Comment: The code snippet looks promising. However, could you specify some dummy data for the ... ellipses? Also, how should I call the START TRANSACTION with the JDBC?

Comment: @coderodde This code snippet doesn't look promising. It is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` that looks promising. This code snippet will create a concurrency bottleneck.

Comment: *`SELECT MAX(bill_num)+1 FROM Bills  FOR UPDATE;`* ?? And what row(s) must be locked for update by this query? PS. `START TRANSACTION;` without precise previous `SET TRANSACTION` specifying may confuse - defaults may differ from server to server.

Comment: @Akina - I think that will lock the last row of the table, which should be sufficient to block the equivalent transaction from another connection.  What is `SET TRANSACTION`?  Transaction isolation is usually not touched by users; I'm assuming the default.

Comment: *I think that will lock the last row of the table* No. MAX() causes implicit GROUP BY - hence none source row is related to the output row. Do not forget that the locking (if used) is index record locking, not table body record locking. *What is `SET TRANSACTION`?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do a 3 phase insert of a new bill record:

1. Create a new record using auto_increment for it's id (primary key).
2. read the record back to get it's id.
   With this id you are able to calculate your bill number.
3. Update the record with the bill number.

But keep in mind to always set a unique constraint on the bill number column!

If this is not an option you have to develop your own sequence generator to have unique numbers. From mySql 5 on you can implement this as stored procedure / function in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Many suggestions here are spot on.

1. `AUTO_INCREMENT` works. However, if you plan to use it for public-facing data, I recommend against it because it's simple to guess the next bill number; just increment bill number by 1. Potentially a security issue.
2. `COUNT(*)` doesn't work. When you have a lot of records, performance will suffer, and if there are deletions, then `COUNT(*)` may actually go backwards and you'll get the same bill number.

Without knowing the requirements of the bill number, I would go with [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) route that P.Salmon recommended. This way, not only that noone can guess the next bill number, but it's quite easy to do as well. Inserting into bills table would be something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO bills VALUES (UUID(), ...)
```

or if you have `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, you may want to do something like

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO bills VALUES (NULL, UUID(), ...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- To get the last inserted id
COMMIT;
```

If UUID string doesn't work for you, you may want to do alternative-scheme, like appending your customer's number and/or generate a numbering scheme similar to how credit card / gift card generates their number.

If bill number is not sensitive information, then the simplest way is to just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` as your bill number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create unique number for Bill without using Auto-Increment etc, one way is you convert your timestamp to bill id by using Java function System.currentTimeMillis(), it will always be unique and secure unless yours bills are getting generated at the rate of more than one per millisecond ;)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) can computed the same bill number of two bills, if you want not to computed, you can set unique index on bill number

COUNT(arg) itself is a MySQL function. COUNT ++ is counted if the arg (column or entire row) in parentheses is not NULL, otherwise the line is not counted.  For details, go to the "Evaluate_join_record and column is empty" section.